# how to hyperlink autocomplete values in drupal 7

Tags: ajax

When users search a hotel name  using Views autocomplete exposed filter text field, is it possible to hyperlink the result values? Suppose we are searching some 'XY' user in a input. The results appear as autocomplete drop-down. When we click on them, it redirects to the hotels description page description page.

Can anyone tell me the best possible solution for this as i tried all but in vain!!!
Is hyperlinking to autocomplete text results possible?

Comment: I'm note sure but I'd rather do that in JS, not necessary with "hyperlink" or something, but with a click listener and redirection.

Comment: Thank you for such a fast response,any other solution regarding this?